# P-value of partial autocorrelation function

Tags: python, correlation, partial, p-value

Goal : Calculate the p-value of the **partial autocorrelation** for order from 2 to 40. Same for the **autocorrelation**.

Currently : I'm using the module **acf** and **pacf** of **"statsmodel"** to calculate the autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation.

```
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import acf, pacf
[accf, qstat, pvalue] = acf(rtrn, unbiased=False, nlags=40, qstat=True, fft=False, alpha=None, missing='none')
paccf = pacf(rtrn, nlags=40, method='ywunbiased', alpha=None) 

# let's say rtrn is known
# rtrn = np.arange(80)
# accf = array([ 1.,  0.9625,  0.92502344, ..., -0.25011721])
# paccf = array([ 1., 0.97468354, -0.02532447, ..., -0.12554433])
# !!! I would like also the p-values of these correllations
```

Can someone tell me the formulas or which modules to use?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow.com! Please make your question a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Also check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make your post answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

p values are related to confidence intervals, in that if you had a p value of exactly 0.05, then your confidence interval at 0.05 would go up to but not past 0.

With that in mind, we can reverse the confidence interval calculation so that instead of having a fixed alpha at 0.05, we make alpha the unknown variable and use our autocorrelation values as the inputs.

If you look in stattools, this is how they calculate confidence intervals:

```
from statsmodels.tsa import stattools
ret = stattools.pacf_ols(x, nlags=40)
varacf = 1. / len(x)  # for all lags >=1
interval = stattools.stats.norm.ppf(1. - alpha / 2.) * np.sqrt(varacf)
confint = np.array(lzip(ret - interval, ret + interval))
```

To invert this equation to solve for p-values, you set interval equal to your pacf values and then solve for alpha.

```
pvalues = stats.norm.sf(abs(ret) / np.sqrt(1. / len(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [statsmodel's "Ljung-Box test"](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.acorr_ljungbox.html)

```
from statsmodels import stats

lbvalues, pvalues = stats.diagnostic.acorr_ljungbox(rtnr) #I guess rtnr is your data to test for
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm looking for the p-values of the **autocorellation** and **partial autocorellation**.